# Heroku app spits out L11 Errorrs (Tail Buffer overflow) and logging freezes

Tags: heroku

I was checking an old app on heroku I was running for several years without a problem. Now the log section freezes and is filled with L11 overflow buffer errors. I can reach the app via HTTP, but some functions are not working anymore and I can not log where the errors happens since the log screen freezes due to the heroku errors messages. From CLI I get same errors.